How to develop portable HTTP clients across js/ts web frameworks?
Related: Best practice for interoperable TypeScript→JavaScript? - Frameworks, browser extensions
Angular, React, Vue, Svelte &etc. exist and are popular. Some use rxjs to flow from HTTP response, others have builtin or other third-party libraries for the same. For example, httpClient implementations include the standard fetch API or Angular's HttpClient from @angular/common/http.
How would one go about writing a client library of HTTP calls [in TypeScript] that could be used across any popular TS/JS web framework?

see Green fields, blue skies, and the white board - what is too broad?

My question is reasonable. How do I write an abstract HTTP client library for popular ts/js frameworks? - Not sure how I can be more specific without asking a question per framework; at which point my abstraction question would remain unanswered

Why not use fetch directly?

Because fetch isn't what's used on, for example, Angular. Its abstraction can be used, for example, to attach Bearer tokens to the Authorisation HTTP header.

Maximum portability comes at a cost. The more portable you make something, the more you need to take charge of the full lifecycle of your library. Basically, as portability increases, the work required to support all the behavior necessary for a functionally complete library increases.

You could provide generic interfaces to support things like authentication, configuration, serialization and parsing (if it makes sense). This would allow framework code to integrate with the lifecycle of your client library.

Build your own support for authentication and data contacts.

For Typescript, this should also include all relevant types and interfaces for your HTTP client. This also couples applications to those contacts, which means breaking changes to your library become even more burdensome to test and distribute.


Now that you have a reusable library, how will you handle bug fixes and distribution; especially security fixes?


You trade independence for complexity when you cannot leverage a particular framework. Coupling your code to a framework can reduce complexity, but also reduces your ability to reuse code without pulling in lots of external dependencies.
There isn't one perfect answer for this. You will need to analyze the trade-off between code reuse and complexity.

Your advice is reasonable. Would be good to see examples of others doing good if you know of any. Meta comment: why is your answer+1 and my question -4? - Weird

It does have a surprising number of down-votes for the number of close votes. I see one vote to close as needing focus. Questions work best if you have a clearly defined design problem. Asking "How would one go about writing a client library" doesn't give us a well defined problem, and that might the reason for the down-votes.

My clearly defined design problem is "how do I support multiple web frameworks with the one codebase" [question got closed] then this one "how do I write an HTTP client that can be supported by multiple web frameworks" and get -4.

Asking 'how do I write' is too open-ended for this community because each answer is equally correct.  The [help/on-topic] has more information about the kinds of questions we do support. I do agree that this question is too broad, but the -4 score without being closed seems harsh.

We see lots of questions where the person needs help brainstorming, but that is almost universally not supported across the StackExchange network. We do have two options, though: [chat] and StackOverflow Discussions. That allows for a more open-ended conversation, which is probably something you would find more appealing.
